# .NET Treeview: How to prevent unchanged child nodes from being redrawn?

Tags: .net, winforms, performance, events, treeview

I'm working with WinForms in .NET 2010. I've created a user control that inherits from Treeview and I'm using owner-drawing for the text part of my treenodes.

Now I had to solve a strange performance problem:

When the text of a treenode (I call it "parentnode") gets changed, the treeview control fires the DrawNode-event for each of "parentnodes"'s child nodes, whether they are visible or not!!!

This is causing a big performance problem for my application. How can I prevent the treeview control from firing the DrawNode event for each child node?

Thx a lot in advance for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get a stellar repro for this, it does only generate DrawNode events for visible nodes.  However, I do see it generate DrawNode events for child nodes whose parent is collapsed.  You can filter those like this:

```
    private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Bounds.Height == 0) return;
        // etc..
    }
```

Comment: thx, that's better. but it still takes nearly one second to get the tv redrawn, while my form is not responding...

for redrawing I use a Backgroundworker which calls a delegate method. in this method tv.beginupdate, treenode.text renaming and tv.endupdate statements are executed.

How can I make my form responding, while these things are executed?

Comment: Ugh, that's punishingly expensive if you do that for every single node.  Update only in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler and use Begin/EndUpdate().  Or batch lots of them in a ReportProgress call.